# It is possible to use html <video> tag to show a Youtube video

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, html5-video

I need to show youtube videos inside the html  tag. I can't use an iframe to put the embedded youtube video.

Is there any real way to do this?

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qh91xRArCwk" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

I want to do it because [Youtube embedded does not allow autoplay](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Autoplay_and_scripted_playback) on ios and android on mobile.

Even if you have the video with the muted parameter, it doesn't play on mobile.

Comment: Maybe you could try playing on client-side both video and audio obtained with links obtained with `youtube-dl -g VIDEO_ID`

Answer (score 0):

You need a **video file** for the `src`, but instead here you are providing a link to a **web page**.

I suggest you save on problems by just using a site like : [GetVideo](https://getvideo.at/en/) : to save a copy of that `.mp4` that you can serve from your website. This way, the video tag should allow `autoplay` on mobile.